# jquery $.ajax throws js error when return header is 404

Tags: jquery

I'm experiencing something odd here, that I don't recall ever running into.  I'm doing a normal $.ajax call to my server (codeigniter backend) and if some resource isn't found, I'm returning some error message along with a 404 header.  jQuery recognizes that an error has occurred and runs the proper error callbacks.  The issue is that it also throws a js exception in the browser, so firebug will complain (or whatever js console the browser might be using).  Is this a new behavior?  I don't recall jquery throwing a js error when a 404 header is returned.  Relevant code below:

```
$.extend({
    gallery: function (url, data) {
        //send a request to an arbitrary url with some data. Expects to
        //get json returned.
        return $.ajax(State.url + url, $.extend({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post'
        }, data));
    }
});
```

Above is my global ajax function I use in my app.  I've tried various flavors of an error functions in that function but to no avail, I always get a js error thrown in firebug.  Any ideas?  The actual js error I'm getting is:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found
```

Comment: yeah, that's weird that it throws a JS exception. you could always wrap it in a `try{}catch{}`, but I don't think it should do that...

Comment: would be curious to see an example of how the errors are being handled. I assume you're using the "error" parameter in the .ajax call (the code supplied is an extension, correct?). You could also use status codes to catch the 404 instead, though you probably don't want to micro-manage every single status code.

Comment: Greg Pettit - I haven't gotten that far yet, so there is no error function for my $.ajax function.  For testing purposes, I have added an error handler to my ajax function above, but I still get a js error in firebug.  I've also tried a myriad of other error headers, (400, 404, 500 just for fun) which give me a js exception.  I've used $.ajax like this before, and don't recall having to worry about using try / catch...

Comment: facepalm...Looks like I had firebug "show network errors" checkbox ticked...sigh...Thanks for taking a look everyone...what's the proper way to close this?  Post the answer and accept it?

Comment: @Greg: If nobody else posted the correct answer, you may post your own answer and then later accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your console feature, not some jQuery gotcha. Try fiddling with your console options. Even Google Chrome tells that XHR failed or something like that.

P.S: Never used firebug. But it must be something in there only.

Comment: You are correct Nishchay, it was a firebug specific setting.  Thanks!